# Ignore "global" scaling in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I'm using several macro's to quickly draw points in a figure (I have to realy draw a lot). For example I use:

```
\newcommand{\punt}[3]{\draw[fill,scale=1]#1 coordinate(#2)circle(0.5pt)node[#3]{$#2$};}
```

to quickly draw a point and it's name, as well as give it the correct coordinate.

My problem is that as I'm drawing I might later decide to scale the entire picture (using `scale`). This results in larger dots that depict the points. I don't want this because I might scale one picture to 2 times it's size and another one to 0.5 it's size and this leads to a discrepancy in dot sizes throughout my document.

An even greater problem arises when I use `xscale` or `yscale` which leads to deformed circles.

Is there a way I can tell my macro to ignore all other scaling?
As you can see I tried putting `scale=1` in the draw options but this didn't help...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `shift only` key. From the manual:

> This option does not take any
>   parameter. Its effect is to cancel all
>   current transformations except for the
>   shifting. This means that the origin
>   will remain where it is, but any
>   rotation around the origin or scaling
>   relative to the origin or skewing will
>   no longer have an effect.
>
> This option
>   is useful in situations where a
>   complicated transformation is used to
>   “get to a position,” but you then wish
>   to draw something “normal” at this
>   position.

The following command first places a coordinate node at the desired location with scaling in effect and then places a circle around that node without scaling:

```
\newcommand{\punt}[3]{
    \draw #1 coordinate (#2);
    \fill[shift only] (#2) circle (0.5pt) node[#3] {$#2$};
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that key.. even though I have been going over and over the Tikz manual to find a solution.
Always good to have the extra knowledge thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following doesn't really answer the actual question, but it does solve your problem.  (And I, for one, would be interested in knowing how to solve the actual question.)

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\punt}[3]{\draw[fill,scale=1]#1 coordinate(#2) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] {} node[#3]{$#2$};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\punt{(0,0)}{a}{above}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[scale=5]
\punt{(0,-1)}{a}{above}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\punt{(0,-2)}{b}{below}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works because the scaling doesn't apply to the shape of nodes, so by drawing the circle using the `node` syntax, the scaling doesn't get applied to the circle size.

Comment: yes this is what I did now.. it works perfectly!